# mouse cursor in navigation menu bootstrap ember

Tags: ember.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap in ember app.

My nav menu does not show a hand with finger pointer on hovering over it instead it show
cursor for text input prompt straight line

```
{{#linkTo "myrequests" tagName="li"}}
    <a {{bind-attr href="view.href"}}>My Request</a>
{{/linkTo}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly set the cursor to pointer in your css--assuming the basic ember sample project, just add the following to your style.css:

```
a {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Stumbled across it here: http://marceldegraaf.net/2013/05/17/ember-js-and-bootstrap-navbar-mark-li-active.html